# How to read CSV file from our computer using .net core web api

Tags: c#, .net, database, asp.net-web-api

Some time we need to import or insert all the CSV files located in a directory into database. The following C# code will insert all the files in a directory into database: const string CSV_CONNECTIONSTRING = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="{0}";Extended Properties="text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited""

Comment: It is better to write code yourself and ask questions about the code you wrote...

Answer (score 3):

As we don't have a lot ot information, we just can give you some tips in order to achieve what you want:

You need to install a NuGet package that provides CSV reading functionality. One sample of it it's "CsvHelper library" [CSV Library](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

Then just use it, you will in the docs how to use it, but one sample of it would be:

```
void Main()
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>();
        foreach (var record in records) {
            // whatever u want
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.